# Delete all unused attribute options.

Tags: t-sql, magento

Attemping to delete all unused attribute options from my magento 1.4.2 store.  What join am I missing?

Edit: Am I deleting from the wrong table?

```
delete eaov
from eav_attribute_option_value eaov
inner join eav_attribute_option eao on eaov.option_id = eao.option_id
inner join eav_attribute ea on ea.attribute_id = eao.attribute_id
left join catalog_product_index_eav ce 
    on ce.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id  and ce.value = eaov.option_id
where ce.entity_id is null
```

Comment: What do you see when you select from eaov?

Comment: i still see all options, even options that are in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comment below for the proper answer.

Comment: This query has some serious problems. Please see this link for more info http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/delete-unused-attribute-values/16123#16123